Autollenado con JS y consulta hacia mysql
Tengo un select con JS que me muestra los clientes que estan grabados en la DB pero necesito que al seleccionar uno en otro input me muestre el idvendedor asociado a ese cliente. Hasta el momento puedo ver los clientes pero no se como hacer para que en el otro input me muestre el código del vendedor.
Si me pueden dar una mano les agradezco.
HTML:
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                <label for="">Cliente</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="idencabezado" id="idencabezado">
                <select name="idcliente" id="idcliente" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <label for="">Vendedor</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="idvendedor" id="idvendedor" readonly>
              </div>

JS:
   $.post("../ajax/venta.php?op=selectCliente", function(r){
$("#idcliente").html(r);
$('#idcliente').selectpicker('refresh');   });

PHP:
    case 'selectCliente':

    $rspta = $venta->listarc();

    while ($reg = $rspta->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<option value=' . $reg->idpersona . '>' . $reg->nombre . '</option>';
    }
    break;

Consulta:
//Seleccionar cliente
public function listarc()
{
    $sql = "SELECT idpersona, nombre, idvendedor FROM persona WHERE tipo_persona = 'Cliente'";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}


Edita tu pregunta y añade el código que acabas de comentar.

Para un dato simple, como es el id, en vez de hacer otro viaje al servidor, lo puedes pre-cargar en un atributo data- y mostrarlo desde cualquier evento. Revisa esta respuesta por ejemplo. En el cliente (HTML / Javascript) los datos se cargan inicialmente, y luego los muestras leyendo los atributos data-

Pero eso me es funcional si mantengo las opciones pero en este caso es necesaria la consulta porque la lista de datos crecera con el tiempo, por eso considero necesaria la consulta y que me regrese la lista de los cliente y al seleccionar me regrese al otro input el vendedor que tiene asignado

La respuesta es lo que te señala @A.Cedano: A los option le añades el código del vendedor dentro de un atributo data-*, por ejemplo data-vendedor:
while ($reg = $rspta->fetch_object()) {
  echo '<option value=' . $reg->idpersona . ' data-vendedor=' . $reg->idvendedor . '  >' . $reg->nombre . '</option>';
}

Luego en javascript creas un evento que cuando cambie el select coloque ese data-vendedor en el input


const input = document.getElementById("idvendedor");

document.getElementById("idcliente").addEventListener("change", (e)=> input.value = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].dataset.vendedor);
<select name="idcliente" id="idcliente" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
  <option id="1" data-vendedor="111">Juan</option>
  <option id="2" data-vendedor="222">Pedro</option>
  <option id="3" data-vendedor="333">Diego</option>
  <option id="4" data-vendedor="444">Marco</option>
</select>

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="idvendedor" id="idvendedor" readonly>



